# neo4j transaction log delete

Tags: linux, neo4j, transaction-log

Storage on my machine is almost full. I need to delete neo4j transaction logs to make some space on the machine. But for safe deletion of transaction logs, it is recommended to stop neo4j first and then delete. But due to insufficient space neo4j is not able to stop. Is there any other alternative or better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure transaction log rotation rule. For example:

```
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1G size;
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/transaction-logs/